# Can case_when report the names of the variables it selects as well as their values?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, case-when

I have a dataset, where for each unique DOI the value of a particular variable is scattered across any combination of three variables (columns). This has occurred because I have searched three different online search engines for DOI information and combined the results into a single file. An example data set is as follows:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  'DOI' = c("A","B","C","D","E", "G", "H", "I")
  , 'V2' = c(1,NA,NA,4,5,NA,7, NA)
  , 'V3' = c(NA,2,NA,4,5,6,NA, NA)
  , 'V4' = c(NA,NA,3,4,NA,6,7, NA)
)

df1

  DOI V2 V3 V4
1   A  1 NA NA
2   B NA  2 NA
3   C NA NA  3
4   D  4  4  4
5   E  5  5 NA
6   G NA  6  6
7   H  7 NA  7
8   I NA NA NA
```

The following code allows me to select the data irrespective of which of the three columns (V2, V3 or V4) it is contained within, and save it in a single new variable V5.

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>% mutate(V5 = case_when((!is.na(V2) & is.na(V3) & is.na(V4)) ~ V2,
                            (is.na(V2) & !is.na(V3) & is.na(V4) ) ~ V3,
                            (is.na(V2) & is.na(V3) & !is.na(V4) ) ~ V4,
                            (!is.na(V2) & !is.na(V3) & !is.na(V4) ) ~ V2,
                            (!is.na(V2) & !is.na(V3) & is.na(V4) ) ~ V3,
                            (is.na(V2) & !is.na(V3) & !is.na(V4) ) ~ V3,
                            (!is.na(V2) & is.na(V3) & !is.na(V4) ) ~ V2,
                            (is.na(V2) & is.na(V3) & is.na(V4) ) ~ V2,
                            TRUE ~ NA_real_))
df2

  DOI V2 V3 V4 V5
1   A  1 NA NA  1
2   B NA  2 NA  2
3   C NA NA  3  3
4   D  4  4  4  4
5   E  5  5 NA  5
6   G NA  6  6  6
7   H  7 NA  7  7
8   I NA NA NA NA
```

I would like to also record (as V6), which of the variables (V2, V3 or V4) was the SOURCE of the data that was copied into V5. I tried the following but it seems to have just copied the value of the variables that went into V5, rather than the NAME of the variable itself.

```
df3 <- df2 %>% mutate(V6 = case_when((!is.na(V2) & is.na(V3) & is.na(V4)) ~ "V2",
                                     (is.na(V2) & !is.na(V3) & is.na(V4) ) ~ "V3",
                                     (is.na(V2) & is.na(V3) & !is.na(V4) ) ~ "V4",
                                     (!is.na(V2) & !is.na(V3) & !is.na(V4) ) ~ "V2",
                                     (!is.na(V2) & !is.na(V3) & is.na(V4) ) ~ "V3",
                                     (is.na(V2) & !is.na(V3) & !is.na(V4) ) ~ "V3",
                                     (!is.na(V2) & is.na(V3) & !is.na(V4) ) ~ "V2",
                                     (is.na(V2) & is.na(V3) & is.na(V4) ) ~ "V2",
                                     TRUE ~ NA_real_))
df3

  DOI V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1   A  1 NA NA  1  1
2   B NA  2 NA  2  2
3   C NA NA  3  3  3
4   D  4  4  4  4  4
5   E  5  5 NA  5  5
6   G NA  6  6  6  6
7   H  7 NA  7  7  7
8   I NA NA NA NA NA
```

Is it possible to also record the name of the variable from which the data was selected? This will allow to track which of the search engines I used to locate the matching DOI information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R option using `max.col` to select the first non-NA value in each row and the corresponding column name.

```
inds <- max.col(!is.na(df1[-1]), 'first')
df1$V5 <- df1[-1][cbind(1:nrow(df1), inds)]
df1$V6 <- names(df1[-1])[inds]
#To replace column name with all NA value to NA
df1$V6[rowSums(!is.na(df1[-1])) == 0] <- NA
```

---

If you are interested in `dplyr` solution you can use `rowwise` with `c_across` :

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(V5 = na.omit(c_across(V2:V4))[1], 
         V6 = names(.)[-1][which(!is.na(c_across(V2:V4)))[1]])

#   DOI      V2    V3    V4    V5 V6   
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#1 A         1    NA    NA     1 V2   
#2 B        NA     2    NA     2 V3   
#3 C        NA    NA     3     3 V4   
#4 D         4     4     4     4 V2   
#5 E         5     5    NA     5 V2   
#6 G        NA     6     6     6 V3   
#7 H         7    NA     7     7 V2   
#8 I        NA    NA    NA    NA NA
```

We use `-1` because we want to ignore the first column `DOI` from the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Using base R:

```
> df1
  DOI V2 V3 V4
1   A  1 NA NA
2   B NA  2 NA
3   C NA NA  3
4   D  4  4  4
5   E  5  5 NA
6   G NA  6  6
7   H  7 NA  7
8   I NA NA NA
> df1$V5 <- apply(df1[2:4], 1, max, na.rm = T)
> df1$V5[is.infinite(df1$V5)] <- NA
> df1$V6 <- apply(df1[2:4],1,which.max)
> df1$V6 <- as.integer(df1$V6)
> df1$V6 <- names(df1)[2:4][df1$V6]
> df1
  DOI V2 V3 V4 V5   V6
1   A  1 NA NA  1   V2
2   B NA  2 NA  2   V3
3   C NA NA  3  3   V4
4   D  4  4  4  4   V2
5   E  5  5 NA  5   V2
6   G NA  6  6  6   V3
7   H  7 NA  7  7   V2
8   I NA NA NA NA <NA>
>
```